# My boss hasn't called me in a week even though she said she would, what should I do?

Tags: communication, new-job, manager, scheduling

Location is in the U.S., if that's relevant.

I just got hired and went through orientation at this company and the manager told me she would call me to schedule my first shift but it's been 9 days and I'm supposed to be starting in 5 days and she still hasn't called me, what should I do?

Comment: Ummm... call her? Send her an email? Send her a text?

Answer (score 5):

**My boss at one job forgot that I was outside for an hour on my first day**

I was sitting in the lobby where I was told to wait. The assistant had told my boss that I was there, but in between leaving his office and coming to get me, someone needed him for something, after which he returned to his office. I had to give him a call to remind him that I was outside.

People forget things. Send her an email to follow up.

Answer (score 3):

> *she would call me to schedule my first shift but it's been 9 days and I'm supposed to be starting in 5 days and she still hasn't called me, what should I do?*

### Communicate.

Communication is the key. The ideal time to get in touch was yesterday, get in touch as soon as possible.

If you have got a number, call them up. Otherwise, send an email politely asking for the shift assignment, and ask them to let you know of the plan for you.